# Can I just pass null as "output buffer" parameter of HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock()?

Tags: c#, .net, hashalgorithm

`HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock()` has `outputBuffer` parameter which is documented as *A copy of the part of the input array used to compute the hash code.* which sounds like my data will be read, used to alter the hash mechanism state and also copied to `outputBuffer`.

I don't need that copying. It looks like I can pass `null` instead and it looks working.

Should I expect any problems if I pass `null` as `outputBuffer`?

Comment: The documentation certainly only talks about `ArgumentNullException` if the input buffer is okay - but doesn't explicitly talk about what happens with a null output buffer. Hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to pass `null`. The reason it even has this parameter is because it's implementing the [`ICryptoTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. This interface can be used when constructing `CryptoStream`s because you might want to build up a set of transformations. In this case, `HashAlgorithm` doesn't change the data at all so it ends up funnily defined as just copying the input to the output.

Other implementations of `ICryptoTransform` (e.g. anything that actually performs encryption or decryption) would of course also be writing non-trivial output.

This means that, during a single pass over an input, you can compute the hash *while* also performing encryption - that's why this interface is supported here.

---

The [current implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/hashalgorithm.cs#e7c6be1ed86f474f) just has this, after it's done its work:

```
 if ((outputBuffer != null) && ((inputBuffer != outputBuffer) ||
      (inputOffset != outputOffset)))
      Buffer.BlockCopy(inputBuffer, inputOffset,
           outputBuffer, outputOffset, inputCount);
```